# Converting hex to binary and then to decimal

Tags: c, arrays, binary, hex, decimal

My code (below) takes a text file with hexadecimal values and converts the hexadecimal value to binary and then to decimal. Then I just want to print the output of the by adding a printf statement in my main function. But I cannot figure out why the printf statement in my main function is wrong? Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int hex_to_binary(char *hex_string, char *binary_line);
int bstr_to_dec(const char * str);

int main()
{
    FILE *file;;
    file = fopen("obj.txt","r");
    char line[200];
    char binary_line[20];

    while(!feof(file)){
        fgets(line,100,file);
        //hex_to_binary(line,binary_line);
        //printf("%s\n", binary_line);
        printf("%d\n",bstr_to_dec((hex_to_binary(line,binary_line))); //This line is having errors
        memset(binary_line,0,20);
    }
    fclose(file);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int hex_to_binary(char *hex_string, char *binary_line)
{
    int i=0;
    while(hex_string[i])
     {
        switch(hex_string[i])
        {
            case '0': strcat(binary_line,"0000"); break;
            case '1': strcat(binary_line,"0001"); break;
            case '2': strcat(binary_line,"0010"); break;
            case '3': strcat(binary_line,"0011"); break;
            case '4': strcat(binary_line,"0100"); break;
            case '5': strcat(binary_line,"0101"); break;
            case '6': strcat(binary_line,"0110"); break;
            case '7': strcat(binary_line,"0111"); break;
            case '8': strcat(binary_line,"1000"); break;
            case '9': strcat(binary_line,"1001"); break;
            case 'A': strcat(binary_line,"1010"); break;
            case 'B': strcat(binary_line,"1011"); break;
            case 'C': strcat(binary_line,"1100"); break;
            case 'D': strcat(binary_line,"1101"); break;
            case 'E': strcat(binary_line,"1110"); break;
            case 'F': strcat(binary_line,"1111"); break;
            case 'a': strcat(binary_line,"1010"); break;
            case 'b': strcat(binary_line,"1011"); break;
            case 'c': strcat(binary_line,"1100"); break;
            case 'd': strcat(binary_line,"1101"); break;
            case 'e': strcat(binary_line,"1110"); break;
            case 'f': strcat(binary_line,"1111"); break;
            case ' ':break;
            case '\n':break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",bstr_to_dec(binary_line));
    return 0;
}

int bstr_to_dec(const char * str) 
{
    int val = 0;     
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        val = 2 * val + (*str++ - '0');
    }
    return val;
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
            printf("%d\n",bstr_to_dec((hex_to_binary(line,binary_line)));
```

Comment: `I cannot figure out why the printf statement in my main function is wrong`.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: more ( than ) and hex_to_binary returns int not string

Comment: Looks like your 3rd question on this programming task.  Note: do not use `while(!feof(file)){ fgets(line,100,file);`, use `while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {`.

Comment: btw, `*binary_line = 0;` = considerably more efficient as just as effective to reset to a zero-length string before your next loop iteration. Iow, the `memset` is complete overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made mistake about usage of 'hex_in_binary' function.

hex_in_binary(char *hex_string, char *binary_line) returns 0 always, and value of binary_line are modified.

You do not use return value of hex_in_binary as first argument of bstr_to_dec, but use binary_line as first argumetn.

In your code, following line

```
    printf("%d\n",bstr_to_dec((hex_to_binary(line,binary_line))); //This line is having errors
```

shoule be corrected as follows

```
    hex_to_binary(line,binary_line);
    printf("%d\n",bstr_to_dec(binary_line));
```

You may need to correct size of binary_line[] as mentioned by Eric J.

Size of binary_line should be larger than the maximum number of hexadecimal characters in a line of the text file you use multiplied by 4.

Answer (score 0):

You have only allocated 20 characters for binary_line

```
char binary_line[20];
```

but the total length of the final output can be significantly longer than 20 characters.  If the hex input is more than 5 hex characters, you will overwrite the memory allocated for `binary_line`.

Each hex character will result in 4 binary digits.

Comment: I'm getting this error:: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
                printf("%d\n",bstr_to_dec((hex_to_binary(line,binary_line)));

Comment: that error is because hex_to_binary returns int, but bstr_to_dec expects a pointer to char

Answer (score 0):

First, you have 4 open brackets '(', and only 3 close brackets ')' on the printf line.

Then we find that hex_to_binary(...) returns an int, but bstr_to_dec(...) is expecting a string parameter.

To use hex_to_binary(...) as a parameter to bstr_to_dec(...) it needs to return a string.

Currently the function modifies the contents of binary_line[] passed in, but you don't use the content after the function completes.  It seems like you intend to return the string but instead return an int value hardcoded to 0.

hint:

```
char *hex_to_binary(char *hex_string)
char binary_line[200];
...
return binary_line;
```

Comment: Where should I insert this^?

Comment: you should rewrite the function to look like this. currently return type is int and you always return 0.  That's just bad programming.